# Nodejs and forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Okay so i know that it is bad pratice to force `node.js` to be syncronous but in this case i have no choice.

I am trying to create a tree like structure of my categories for this i have created this function:

```
    router.route('/api/categoryStructure')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        var cat = Category.build();
        cat.getRootCategories(function (categories) {
            var result = [];
            var root = categories;
            root.forEach(function (y) {
                var tmp = findTree(y);
                    result.push(tmp);
            });
        })
    });


function findTree(rootCategory) {
    var root = [rootCategory];
    var result = [];
    (function loop() {
        var element = root[0];
        var category = Category.build();
        category.retrieveByParentId(element.id, function (categories) {
            if (categories) {
                element.dataValues.subcategories = categories;
                categories.forEach(function (division) {
                    root.push(division);
                });

                root.splice(0, 1);

                if (result.length == 0) {
                    result.push(element);
                    loop()

                }
                else if (root.length == 0) {
                    return result;
                }
                else {
                    loop()
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = root;
                return result;
            }
        });
    }());
}
```

Now as you can see it loop through each of the root categories to find all subcategories and all of their subcategories.

This works perfectly fine however there is a problem

The `tmp` variable in my loop is set to `undefined` because of the asyncronous behavior of `node`. This means that my array is being filled up with `undefined`/ `null` values.

So my question is how can i avoid this?

Comment: Is `category.retrieveByParentId` asynchronous? I'm guessing it is, what with the callback, but...

Comment: Also, note that `findTree` has no return value at all. You sometimes return a value out of the callback you're passing into `retrieveByParentId`, but you're never returning a value from `findTree`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder il update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First solution:**
Lets add some logic to `findTree` to make it accepts callbacks

```
function findTree(rootCategory, callback) {
    var root = [rootCategory];
    var result = [];
    (function loop() {
        var element = root[0];
        var category = Category.build();
        category.retrieveByParentId(element.id, function (categories) {
            if (categories) {
                element.dataValues.subcategories = categories;
                categories.forEach(function (division) {
                    root.push(division);
                });

                root.splice(0, 1);

                if (result.length == 0) {
                    result.push(element);
                    loop()

                }
                else if (root.length == 0) {
                    callback(result);
                }
                else {
                    loop()
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = root;
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    }());
}
```

then you can now call `findTree` with a callback having any logic you want to be executed secondly.

```
findTree(y,function(data){
   result.push(data);
});
```

**Another way using async module.**
You could use async module . Its auto function is awesome . If you have function A() and function B() and function C() . Both function B() and C() depend of function A() that is using value return from function A() . using async module function you could make sure that function B and C will execute only when function A execution is completed .

Ref : https://github.com/caolan/async

```
async.auto({
            A: functionA(){//code here },
            B: ['A',functionB(){//code here }],
            C: ['A',functionC(){//code here }],
            D: [ 'B','C',functionD(){//code here }]
        }, function (err, results) {
              //results is an array that contains the results of all the function defined and executed by async module
              // if there is an error executing any of the function defined in the async then error will be sent to err  and as soon as err will be produced execution of other function will be terminated
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: Plus one because I didn't know about auto function in async

Comment: @Mouneer the problem is that my findTree function has an inner loop which makes this impossible :S

Comment: Ok see the "First solution" in my edited answer and please inform me if this answers your question or you still need help